# Как расставить знаки препинания в придаточном с присоединением?

Tags: пунктуация

> Но Супругов был занят папиросой, которая почему-то потухла, — должно
>   быть, гильза была рваная.

Почему здесь запятая перед тире? Ведь часть после тире, судя по смыслу относится к придаточной части, а не ко всему сложноподчиненную предложения перед тире.

> Но Супругов был занят папиросой, которая почему-то потухла, должно
>   быть гильза была рваная.

Можно ли так расставить знаки препинания, объяснив их тем, что часть после "потухла" - это присоединение в придаточной части, а запятой после "должно быть" нет, так как по правилу вводное в присоединении не отделяется от него запятой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Но Супругов был занят папиросой, которая почему-то потухла, — должно быть гильза была рваная.*

Здесь тире, обозначающее паузу,  ставится на границе СПП и простого предложения, которое относится не к придатчному, а ко всему СПП (тем более в СПП не союзная, а местоименная связь, то есть это СПП нерасчлененной структуры).

Связь между СПП и простым предложением бессоюзная, поэтому ставится тире. Запятая закрывает придаточное.

Пояснение

Присоединительное придаточное Розенталь выделяет в следующем предложении (здесь наречие в роли присоединительного союза): *Необходимы были всякие меры предосторожности, особенно если приходилось идти ночью.*

Это БСП из ПАС: Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня (Ч.).
Лопатин позволяет не обособлять вводное слово в таких случаях, но присоединительным второе предложение он не считает.